# using generic method in abstract class with child class result

Tags: c#, generics

I'm working to DRY some code up and I'm running into the following situation. I've reworked the code to provide a better example of the scenario.

```
namespace SourceCode
{
    public interface IFactory
    {
        public baseClass GenerateClass();
        public bool IsUsable();
    } 

    public abstract baseClass
    {
        ...
    }

    public AClass:baseClass
    {
        ...
    }

    public class FactoryA:IFactory
    {
        public baseClass GenerateClass()
        {
            return new AClass();
        }

        public bool IsUsable(){
        {
            return true if some condition;
        }
    }

    public BClass:baseClass
    {
        ...
    }

    public class FactoryB:IFactory
    {
        public baseClass GenerateClass()
        {
            return new BClass();
        }

        public bool IsUsable(){
        {
            return true if some condition;
        }
    }

    public static class FactoryProvider
    {
        List<IFactory> factories
        static FactoryProvider()
        {
            factories.Add(new FactoryA());
            factories.Add(new FactoryB());
        }

        static List<baseClass> GetClasses()
        {
            return (from f in factories where f.IsUsable() select f).ToList();
        }
    }
}

namespace SourceCode.Tests
{
    public class baseTests
    {
        public T GenericMethod<T>(){...}
    }

    public class ClassATests:baseTests
    {
        public void Test1()
        {
            ... generic used in a method provided by the base class
        }
    }

    public class ClassBTests:baseTests
    {
        public void Test1()
        {
            ... generic used in a method provided by the base class
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem in my tests is that there are tests that will have to happen for every child class.

UPDATE=======================
I was able to solve my issue by doing the following.

```
namespace SourceCode.Tests
{
    public class baseTests<I> where I: baseClass
    {
        public void Test1()
        {
            var result = GenericMethod<I>();
            // The generic method will use ClassA for ClassATests
            // and ClassB for ClassBTests
        }

        public T GenericMethod<T>(){...}
    }

    public class ClassATests:baseTests<ClassA>
    {            
    }

    public class ClassBTests:baseTests<ClassB>
    {            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what `SharedMethodHappensAlways` might do?  Also, it will need a return type.

Comment: What about `src.FirstOrDefault(a => this.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(a.GetType()));`

Comment: Are you looking for the [Curiously Recurring Generic Pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx)?

Comment: Jeffery, the shared method would be a common method, I tried to keep it as generic as possible and forgot to add a type to the signature.  

Agent-j the lambda expression I'm using is working just the way I need it too, but I do appreciate the comment.  

dtb, that pattern looks interesting but I'm not sure if that's what i'm aiming for, i'll have to read up on it some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your current `A` class generic could solve problems:

```
abstract class A
{
    // protected members...
    protected abstract A InternalGetData(List<A> src);

    public void SharedMethodHappensAlways()
    {
        List<A> src = new List<A>();
        var childResult = InternalGetData(src);
    }  
}

abstract class A<T> : A
    where T: A
{   
    public T GetData(List<A> src)
    {
        return src.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();
    }

    protected override A InternalGetData(List<A> src)
    {
        return GetData(src);
    }
}    

class B : A<B>
{    
}

class C : A<C>
{    
}
```

Sample usage:

```
List<A> src = new List<A>() { new B(), new C() };
B b = new B();
b.SharedMethodHappensAlways();
B firstB = b.GetData(src); // returns first instance of B
C firstC = new C().GetData(src);
```